# How to concatenate two dataframes in pandas correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to concatenate different dataframes. I have done it successfully for p1 and p2 and got output as expected. But after loading test.csv and concatenate it with p4, I didn't get desired result. p4 creates its own column. I just want that p4 appears right below p3 without creating its own columns. [The image shows my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBHui.png)

Here is my code,

```
import pandas as pd
p1 = pd.DataFrame([['john','Kim'],[9,3]])
p2 = pd.DataFrame([['Alice'],[4]])

p1.index = ['A','']
p2.index = ['B', '']

p3 = pd.concat([p1,p2]).fillna('')
p3.to_csv('test.csv', index = True)

#Again read csv file
p3 = pd.read_csv('test.csv',index_col=0)
p4 = pd.DataFrame([['George'],[7]])
p4.index=['K','']
p5 = pd.concat([p3,p4])
```

I am expecting the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The column names for `p3` are strings "0" and "1". And the column name for `p4` is an `int`: 0. You could convert the columns of `p3` to `int` during the `concat`:

```
>>> pd.concat([p3.rename(columns={i: int(i) for i in p3.columns}),p4])

          0    1
A      john  Kim
NaN       9    3
B     Alice  NaN
NaN       4  NaN
K    George  NaN
          7  NaN
```

Comment: That really helps. Thanks a lot

Comment: Happy to help! :). Note that you can replace `NaN` with empty strings using `fillna("")` at the end of the `concat`

Comment: solved my problem. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your indexes are not the same even if they appear to be:

```
>>> p3.columns  # before to_csv
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)  # numeric

>>> p3.columns  # after read_csv
Index(['0', '1'], dtype='object')  # strings

>>> p4.columns
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1, step=1)  # numeric

>>> p5.columns
Index(['0', '1', 0], dtype='object')  # this is the problem: '0' != 0
```

So if use `p3` created with `pd.concat`, it works:

```
>>> pd.concat([p3, p4])
        0    1
A    john  Kim
        9    3
B   Alice     
        4     
K  George  NaN
        7  NaN
```

But if you use `p3` after `read_csv`, it doesn't work because columns are strings (and not numeric):

```
>>> pd.concat([p3, p4])
         0    1       0
A     john  Kim     NaN
NaN      9    3     NaN
B    Alice  NaN     NaN
NaN      4  NaN     NaN
K      NaN  NaN  George
       NaN  NaN       7
```

You have to cast the columns as numeric:

```
p3 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0)
p3.columns = p3.columns.astype(int)
```

Output:

```
>>> p3.columns
Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')  # numeric, compatible with RangeIndex

>>> pd.concat([p3, p4])
          0    1
A      john  Kim
NaN       9    3
B     Alice  NaN
NaN       4  NaN
K    George  NaN
          7  NaN
```

Comment: I have just one more question?. i do not want row index 'Nan', is it possible to remove it

Comment: Something like `p3.index = p3.index.fillna('')`?